# how to edit costmap data manually?

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d-ros, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :) i wanna edit costmap data manually. i have x and y location of map data given by hector_mapping. and my costmap_2d_ros_ data is runs ok like this:

```
costmap_2d_ros_ = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("global_costmap", tfl_);
```

how can i do?

```
costmap_2d::Costmap2D costmap_temp;
costmap_2d_ros_->getCostmapCopy(costmap_temp);

int map_width = costmap_temp.getSizeInCellsX();
int map_height = costmap_temp.getSizeInCellsY();
int num_map_cells = map_width * map_height;

const unsigned char* occupancy_grid_array;
occupancy_grid_array = costmap_temp.getCharMap();

geometry_msgs::PoseStamped lethal_obstacle;
point.pose.position.x=0.1;
point.pose.position.y=0.1;

if(??? QUESTION1 ???)
{
    ??? QUESTION2 ???=costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
}

??? QUESTION3 ??? now convert costmap_2d::Costmap2D (costmap_temp) to costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64923/how-to-edit-costmap-data-manually?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One solution is to format your incoming data as a PointCloud and go through existing channels for editing the costmap.

However, if you want to do it in code, you can edit the underlying charMap like this.

```
unsigned int mx, my;
costmap_temp.worldToMap(point.pose.position.x, point.pose.position.y, &mx, &my);
costmap_temp.setCost(mx, my, LETHAL_OBSTACLE);
```

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3